# Sum of orthogonal projection operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be an Hilbert space, I am trying to see that if $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal projection operators then the following are equivalent:

$(1) Im Q\subseteq KerP$

$(2)P+Q$ is an orthogonal projection operator.

I was able to do $(1) \implies (2)$ but I cant seem to make the other one so any tips are aprecciated, what I tried revolves around this

From the condition that $P+Q$ is a projection operator I know that $PQ=-QP$ but I cant seem to see why this will have to be zero, I dont know if looking at the decompositions of the space $X$ would be righ way to look at this, also tried using the fact that the operator is positive but got nowhere.

Also another thing I am trying to see is that $Im(P+Q)$ is the closure of the subspace generated by $Im P$ and $Im  Q$, and any advice here would be aprecciated too, I was able to show that $cl(span\{ImP+ImQ\})\subseteq Im(P+Q)$.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us take $f\in Im(Q)$ and hence $Qf=f$ because $Q$ is a projection. Now apply $P$ on both sides to obtain $$Pf=PQf=-QPf.$$

Apply $Q$ on both sides and use that $Q^2=Q$ to obtain $QPf=-QPf.$ Which gives $QPf=0$ and hence $PQf=0.$ Now again using the fact that $Qf=f$ we get $Pf=0$ which yields the claim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but one thing you have $f\in Im(PQ)$ and you claim that $PQf=f$ now why is this true ? I dont see why $PQ$ as to be a projection operator.

Comment: I have edited the answer. I relaised it was much simpler. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yeah that seems alright , Thanks ! By the way do you have any idea on how I can prove the statement about the Image? @WhoKnowsWho

Comment: Can you show that $Im(P) \subseteq Im(P+Q)$? Once you have that an exact mirror argument $Im(Q)\subseteq Im(P+Q)$. It follows that $Im(P)+Im(Q)$ is also contained in $Im(P+Q).$ Since the $Im(P+Q)$ is closed, your desired statement follows.

Comment: Yes I was able to do that inclusion by that argument , not sure how to do $Im(P+Q)\subset cl(span(ImP+ ImQ))$, @WhoKnowsWho